# How can I take the average of only certain rows and columns of a 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, function, average

I have to take the average of only the test grades and put them into the last column but I have no idea how to do it. I have the function for the 2D array that takes in a filename that contains the grades but the first column is the student id so I don't need to take the average of that.

This is the code I have for the 2D array function.

```
#define x 10
#define y 6

void getData(float arr1[x][y])
{
  FILE* graFile;
  float arr2[x][y];
  char userIn[50];
  printf("Enter the text filename: ");
  scanf("%s", userIn);
  graFile = fopen(userIn, "r");
  int studentId, test1, test2, test3, test4;
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
  {
    if(graFile != NULL)
    {
      fscanf(graFile, "%d%d%d%d%d", &studentId, &test1, &test2, &test3, &test4);
      arr2[i][0] = studentId;
      arr2[i][1] = test1;
      arr2[i][2] = test2;
      arr2[i][3] = test3;
      arr2[i][4] = test4;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("\nThis file does not exist.");
      return;
    }
  }
  printf("\n %11s%11s%11s%11s%11s%11s", "Student Id","Test 1","Test 2","Test 3","Test 4","Final\n");
  printf("*********************************************************************\n");
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
      printf("%11.0f", arr2[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("*********************************************************************\n");
  fclose(graFile);
  return;
}
```

That gives me this output

```
Enter the text filename:  grades.txt

  Student Id     Test 1     Test 2     Test 3     Test 4     Final
*********************************************************************
       6814         85         86         92         88          0
       7234         76         81         84         78          0
       6465         87         54         68         72          0
       7899         92         90         88         86          0
       9901         45         78         79         80          0
       8234         77         87         84         98          0
       7934         76         91         84         65          0
       7284         56         81         87         98          0
       7654         76         87         84         88          0
       3534         86         81         84         73          0
*********************************************************************
```

Now I just need to create a new function that averages the test grades from this array and put it into the last column but I'm having trouble doing that. I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: arr2[i][5] = (test1 + test2 + test 3 + test4) / 4;

Comment: Besides the obvious answer above, your program has several issues:

1. if(graFile != NULL) needs to be outside the for loop, not inside.

2. return value of fscanf needs to be checked; unless you're absolutely sure the file always contains at least x rows and the format is always consistent with your fscanf.

Comment: Do you know how I could do that in a function of its own? The file only contains that amount of rows because this is a project for school so it will never be modified. So once I put the if condition outside the loop will my code be okay?

Comment: A function take a float[x][y] as parameter, where the 1st column is student id, 2-5 columns are scores, the function saves the average to the last (6th) column. Is this you need?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

```
void setAverage(float arr[][y], int x) {
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        arr[i][5] = (arr[i][1] + arr[i][2] + arr[i][3] + arr[i][4]) / 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Quick question though, where would I add my printf statement at?

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.